# Can anyone tell me why the icing isn't producing an "ooze" effect?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

I have an image showing all of my selected options, which I think are correct? Except, when I try and select a vertex and use "g" to grab and drag to pull the icing down, it clips into the donut instead of sliding down the surface as I believe it should.

I'm a noob here, but any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: [why is the icing inside of donut and not on top](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162648/why-is-the-dribbling-icing-inside-of-donut-instead-of-being-on-the-top)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.

You have enabled the snapping option. Change the offset in your Solidify Modifier (1 or -1) of the icing part.

Remember, when you grab that point, you will pull the part and at a certain point, the vertices that are at the top that point will intersect with the donut. You can prevent that by adding or subdivide your face. With that, you will have more points to control for the ooze effect