# Why is my icing still going inside my doughnut even after I enabled snapping?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, extrude, snapping

There're 3 identical threads without answers.
I'm following the Blender Guru tutorial and I've done everything as described in the tutorial, but as I pressed E to add the dribbles for the icing the dribbles are always inside the doughnut instead of on top

[image]

[image: without editing mode]
[image: editing mode]
[image: editing mode, side view]

Comment: There's also one question with four answers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162648/why-is-the-dribbling-icing-inside-of-donut-instead-of-being-on-the-top?rq=1 and one with 1 answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162648/why-is-the-dribbling-icing-inside-of-donut-instead-of-being-on-the-top?rq=1.

Comment: this threads do not have any right answers

Comment: You'll need to upload the blend file so that we can have a look in that case: https://blend-exchange.com/help or https://pasteall.org/blend/.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=GpmJd7vg" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/GpmJd7vg/)Here it is

Comment: Not had a chance to look at your file, but I see that there's a thread with 92 replies in the comments below Andrew's part 4 Donut video from "Nic En" discussing your issue so it might be worth looking there.

Comment: Before creating this thread I looked it up, yeah
But thanks anyway

Comment: Incidentally, I see you're using Blender 2.92. - You may have problems later in the tutorials because I believe Andrew uses geometry nodes for the icing sprinkles and there have been a lot of changes in Blender since the version you're using.

Comment: Maybe, yeah, I'll try previous version. Thanks again~

Answer (score 0):

Are you extruding or pulling the icing layer down?   If you deform the layer above, it will naturally intersect with the one below.
Quick workaround, Delete all the "hidden" faces below the icing layer.  Done;